# Passing large object as a pure argument or object

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

My question is very simple, will the `veryLargeObj` pass as a reference in both? And if yes, Is there any performance hit between both examples other than an object creation?

**sample 1:**

```js
import veryLargeObj from './here'

function someFn(veryLargeObj){
    ...
}
```

**sample 2:**

```js
import veryLargeObj from './here'

function someFn( {veryLargeObj} ){
    ...
}
```

Also, will the sample 2 argument be created like the following:

```
                           {"veryLargeObj": veryLargeObj}
normal property name  -------^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^------- reference to large obj?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they'll be the exact same object. For example, if the first module imported the second module and interacted with each other somehow, they'd see that the imported objects are `===`.

The only significant overhead is as you've pointed out, at object creation. The top level of an ES6 module will only run once, even if it's imported multiple places.

But I think you have the notation mixed up a bit:

```
import veryLargeObj from './here'

function someFn(veryLargeObj){
    ...
}
```

Here, you aren't using the large object anywhere - rather, you're declaring that `someFn` takes a *parameter* that happens to be named `veryLargeObj`. If you wanted to use the import, either do something like

```
import veryLargeObj from './here'

function someFn(){
    // use veryLargeObj here
}
```

or

```
import veryLargeObj from './here'

function someFn(veryLargeObj){
    // use veryLargeObj here
}
someFn(veryLargeObj);
```

Same for the other module.